# обновление строки в случае изменения значения в этой строке

Tags: mysql, sql

есть таблица куда записывается последнее действие пользователя:

```
id | user | status | time

1  | user | err    | 11:50
```

столбец user уникален.

Нужно обновить time в случае изменения статуса на любое значение кроме err, как это сделать без проверки на клиенте и одним запросом? Значение которое записано в status заранее не известно

Comment: `update ... set status=$status, time=if($status!='err',новое_значение_time, time)` где `$status` новый статус пришедший с клиента

Comment: по-моему проще не делать запрос в БД вовсе, в случае если статус `err` ...............`сделать без проверки на клиенте` - чем этот вариант не устраивает?  лучше конечно не на клиенте а на сервере проверять

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**:
Принимать решение на клиенте. Использовать возвращаемое количество обновлённых строк чтобы понять изменилось ли что-то. Если да, то вторым запросом изменить ещё и время. Вам не понадобится сравнивать старое и новое, MySQL сделает это сам, в `affected rows` считаются только те строки, которые получили новые значения. Если вы апдейтите одну строку, `affected rows` будет либо 1, либо 0.

**Вариант 2**:
Использовать столбец типа TIMESTAMP с модификатором ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Точто так же, как и в предыдущем случае, MySQL сам поймёт применили ли вы новые значения или они совпадают со старыми. И только в том случае когда что-то изменилось, сработает правило для отметки времени.

Подробности здесь:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_table BEFORE UPDATE ON `table`
BEGIN
    IF NEW.status != 'err' THEN
        SET NEW.`time` = SYSDATE();
    END IF;
END;
```